# Mid-arrow tip in tikz-cd

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd

I would like to place an arrow tip in the middle of an arrow, like one does in TikZ with `markings`, but in a `tikz-cd` diagram. The documentation seems not to tell me anything about how to achieve this. I thought of using `\to` as a `description`. I haven't tried that yet, and it may work fine, but it seems cumbersome to use a label description to achieve a mid-arrow tip. Is there a more semantically proper way to do this?

Comment: That would be easy with `pstricks`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tikz-cd` is still Tikz, so you can use `\tikzset` to set up a style for the middle arrow. Of course, this means that `markings` works as well.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    marrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{#1}}}, postaction=decorate}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
a \ar[rrr, marrow=>] & & & b \\[2mm]
c \ar[rrr, -Latex, marrow=Latex] & & & d
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```