# How to write matrix inside nodes?

Tags: tikz-cd, draw, tikz-matrix, tikz-node

Any tips on how to draw something like this?[image: this one]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun....we can considered your image like a commutative diagram.
PS: the structure

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    marrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.55 with {\arrow{#1}}}, postaction=decorate}
}
```

is taken from [Mid-arrow tip in tikz-cd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326808/mid-arrow-tip-in-tikz-cd) by the user *@Alenanno*.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    marrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.55 with {\arrow{#1}}}, postaction=decorate}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1pt, column sep=normal]
 & \left \{\begin{array}{cc}
x =  y \\
A =  B \end{array} \right.\\
\left \{\begin{array}{cc}
x =  y \\
A =  B \end{array} \right. \ar[rd, marrow=>,"f\neq 0"'{sloped, pos=0.5},no head] \ar[ru,marrow=>,"f=0"{sloped, pos=0.5},no head] &   \\
 & \left \{\begin{array}{cc}
x =  y \\
A =  B \end{array} \right.
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]